ASP.NET Web Api - return JSON response with space in property names
I want my ASP.NET Web API to return a JSON response with spaces in property names. Currently when I am testing it using Postman, I am getting response in this format:
[
  {
     "appId": 1,
     "appName": "app1"
  },
  {
     "appId": 2,
     "appName": "app2"
  }
]

But I would like my Web API to return the response in the format shown here, because in the FE I am reading the column names dynamically and displaying as it it just by converting it to uppercase
[
  {
     "appId": 1,
     "app Name": "app1"
  },
  {
     "appId": 2,
     "app Name": "app2"
  }
]

To achieve this, I tried converting my model to this format:
public class MyApp
{
   public int AppId {get; set;}
   
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "App Name")]
   public string AppName {get; set;}
}

But I still see that the response returned by my API uses the property as appName.
How can I get a JSON property with a space in them?

What JSON serializer/deserializer are you using?  For example, if JsonProperty is part of Newtonsoft but the application is using System.Text.Json then the two are not interchangeable.  They have different attributes.

@David I am using Newtonsoft.Json JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>(response.Content)

In that case I'm not able to replicate the issue: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ktjzW5

Are you using newtonsoft or System.Text.Json as default serialization. Try System.Text.Json attribute JsonPropertyName.
could you please share your code
DTO With JsonPropertyName Attribute
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class UserDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; init; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("Terms And Conditions Agreed")]
    public bool TermsAndConditionsAgreed { get; set; }
}

     

JSON Options Setup
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(opt =>
    {
        opt.SerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
        opt.SerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
        opt.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
        opt.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        opt.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase));
    });


Hi @waqas I am using Newtonsoft.json deserializing using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>(response.Content)

not able to replicate, could you please share how have you setup your API and .csproj file. directly calling serialize/deserialize works fine.

In my model i removed namespace Newtonsoft.Json and used System.text.json.serialization namespace and used [JsonPropertyName("App Name")] attiribute and this fixed the issue.
